# Find closest struct to given struct property in array of structs?

Tags: swift, algorithm

How can I find the closest struct in an array of structs if given a struct of the same type?

```
let people = [
    Person(
        name: "Tom",
        height: 104.0
    ),
    Person(
        name: "James",
        height: 80.0
    ),
    Person(
        name: "Sam",
        height: 110.0
    )
]

let jeff = Person(
    name: "Jeff",
    height: 78.0
)
```

What I want to do is search the `people` array and find the result that closest matches the `height` of jeff.

Comment: Loop through the `people` array and take a record of the person with the least absolute difference.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do a simple for loop through `people`.

```swift
var closest = Person(
    name: "super tall guy",
    height: 999.0
)
var diff:Float = 999

for person in people {
    let currDiff = abs(person.height - jeff.height)
    if (currDiff < diff) {
        closest = person
        diff = currDiff
    }
}

print(closest)
```

Comment: Could you explain the use of `abs` more? That's the part that's confusing me.

Comment: That turns whatever input you put in it into a positive number. For example, `abs(-10)` gives `10`, `abs(10)` gives `10`. You want to get the person with the least height difference. So you want to treat the height difference of `-10` or `10` as the same.

Answer (score 0):

you could try a different approach than using an explicit for loop, such as in this example code.

```
 struct Person: Identifiable, Codable {
     let id = UUID()
     var name: String
     var height: Double
     
     func compare(to other: Person) -> Double { // <-- here
         abs(height - other.height)
     }
  }
 
    // -- here
    let closest = people.min{$0.compare(to: jeff) < $1.compare(to: jeff)}

    print("\n---> closest: \(closest)")
```

Comment: did my answer not work for you?